# How to specify java runtime option in build.sbt or intellij-idea

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, sbt, scala-breeze

I am trying to learn scala and this is my first language on the JVM, so apologies for asking what is probably a basic question. I am trying to use a specific BLAS/LAPACK library for [netlib-java](https://github.com/fommil/netlib-java). This can be achieved by adding the sbt flag:

sbt -J"-Dcom.github.fommil.netlib.BLAS=com.github.fommil.netlib.NativeRefBLAS"

From the man pages of sbt
"-J-X   pass option -X directly to the java runtime (-J is stripped)"

However I don't usually run my application from command line like this, I'm using intellij-idea and was wondering how I can configure it to take this option or whether this option can be specified in my build.sbt file?

Answer (score 0):

You can set JVM options in IDEA's [run configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/run-debug-configuration-application.html) (without `-J`).